# .setBounds not applying to a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

I'm having trouble applying .setBounds to a JLabel. It works with the previous JLabel I defined, but completely disregards my second definition of bounds. I messed with a the width and height a little to see if it was even affecting the JLabel, and it wasn't. Also, I noticed when reversing the addition of my two JLabels, the "greet" label no longer appeared. Heres my code, any help is appreciated :^ )

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Fashion {
    static JFrame f = new JFrame("Game Title");
    static Font h1 = new Font("courier", Font.PLAIN, 30);
    static Font h2 = new Font("courier", Font.PLAIN, 17);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f.setSize(1400, 900);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JLabel title = new JLabel("Welcome!");
        title.setFont(h1);

        JLabel greet = new JLabel("Lets get started.");
        greet.setFont(h2);

        title.setBounds(225,1,1000,100);
        greet.setBounds(350,200,1,1);

        f.add(title);
        f.add(greet);


        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

(ignore the very ugly bounds / placement, theyre oddly specific but its what my professor wants :/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having trouble applying .setBounds to a JLabel. It works with the previous JLabel I defined, but completely disregards my second definition of bounds.

Both of your setBounds(...) statements are ignored.

Swing uses layout managers to set the size and location of components. Even if you try to set the bounds the layout manager will override the size/location values based on the rules of the layout manager.

> Also, I noticed when reversing the addition of my two JLabels, the "greet" label no longer appeared

This is because you are adding both components to the `CENTER` of the `BorderLayout` (which is the default layout manager for the content pane of the frame). Only one component can be displayed so only the last one added is visible.

The solution to your problem is to learn to use layout manager properly. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples to get you started.

The default layout manager is a FlowLayout

Comment: So was it just a mishap that the first .setBounds was displayed correctly? I was able to change the position with the designated coordinates along with the width and such despite the layout...

Comment: `So was it just a mishap that the first .setBounds was displayed correctly?` yes. You have to get into the details of how Swing painting of components works. Basically a component needs a size/location in order to be painted. In your case the BorderLayout only gave a size/location to the second component added and ignored the first component. However Swing paints component in the reverse order they are added to the panel (called the zOrder) so in effect the "greet" component got painted and then the "title" component was painted over top.

Comment: So actually your are correct. Because of the order of your code and the way the components are added to the panel, your first setBounds(...) statement did have an effect. However, the point of my answer is `don't use setBounds()` at all and let layout managers do their job so you don't get confusing results.

Comment: alright, thank you! that makes a lot more sense.. the only reason i used it in the first place was because my professor suggested using it to give the panel "more versatility" or something like that, but i'm definitely going to try to get around that. thanks again !